# Fetching entities in CoreData causing a crash

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsfetchrequest

I have a model which looks like this and contains NSManagedObject properties, namely the `blendsWith` property which is a type of `[Tag]`:

```
extension Oil {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Oil> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Oil>(entityName: "Oil")
}

@NSManaged public var blendsWith: [Tag]?
@NSManaged public var color: String?
@NSManaged public var commentsCount: Int64
@NSManaged public var id: Int64
@NSManaged public var imageURL: String?
@NSManaged public var latinName: String?
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var properties: NSObject?
@NSManaged public var research: String?
@NSManaged public var resourceType: String?
@NSManaged public var viewsCount: Int64

}

public class Oil: NSManagedObject, Codable {

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case resourceType = "resource_type"
    case id, name
    case imageURL = "image_url"
    case color
    case latinName = "latin_name"
    case emotions
    case safetyInformation = "safety_information"
    case fact, research
    case viewsCount = "views_count"
    case commentsCount = "comments_count"
    case blendsWith = "blends_with"
    case foundInBlends = "found_in_blends"
    case properties
    case sourcingMethods = "sourcing_methods"
    case usages
}

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let context = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Oil", in: context) else { fatalError() }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    self.resourceType = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .resourceType)!
    self.id = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .id)!
    self.name = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)!
    self.imageURL = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .imageURL)!
    self.color = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .color)!
    self.viewsCount = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .viewsCount)!
    self.viewsCount = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .viewsCount)!
    self.commentsCount = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .commentsCount)!
    self.latinName = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .latinName)!

    if let blendsWith = try container.decodeIfPresent([Tag].self, forKey: CodingKeys.blendsWith) {
        self.blendsWith = blendsWith
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

}
```

}

`Tag` looks like this:

```
extension Tag {

@nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Tag> {
    return NSFetchRequest<Tag>(entityName: "Tag")
}

@NSManaged public var id: Int64
@NSManaged public var name: String?
@NSManaged public var resourceType: String?
@NSManaged public var tagType: String?
@NSManaged public var viewsCount: Int64

}

public class Tag: NSManagedObject, Codable {

enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case resourceType = "resource_type"
    case id, name
    case viewsCount = "views_count"
    case tagType = "tag_type"
}

required convenience public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let context = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.persistentContainer.viewContext
    guard let entity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Tag", in: context) else { fatalError() }

    self.init(entity: entity, insertInto: context)

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

    self.resourceType = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .resourceType)!
    self.id = try! container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .id)!
    self.name = try! container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .name)!
    if let viewsCount = try container.decodeIfPresent(Int64.self, forKey: .viewsCount) {
        self.viewsCount = viewsCount
    } else  {
        self.viewsCount = 0
    }
    if let tagType = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .tagType) {
        self.tagType = tagType
    } else {
        self.tagType = "lol"
    }
}

public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {

}
```

}

When I go to fetch the `Oil` data stored locally, I get this crash:

```
2018-08-29 20:31:30.602764+0100 EL[27994:14799374] -[EL.Tag initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c000679980
2018-08-29 20:31:30.603905+0100 EL[27994:14799374] [error] error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x608000181ee0> , -[EL.Tag initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c000679980 with userInfo of (null)
CoreData: error: exception handling request: <NSSQLFetchRequestContext: 0x608000181ee0> , -[EL.Tag initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c000679980 with userInfo of (null)
2018-08-29 20:31:30.612185+0100 EL[27994:14799374] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[EL initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x60c000679980'
```

What could be causing this crash?

For reference, my fetching method looks like this:

```
func getItems<T : NSManagedObject>(predicate : NSPredicate? = nil) -> [T]{
        do {
            let reqest = T.fetchRequest()
            reqest.predicate = predicate
            if let items = try persistentContainer.viewContext.fetch(reqest) as? [T] {
                return items
            } else {
                return [T]()
            }
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            return [T]()
        }
    }
```

And works like this:

```
let arrat : [Oil] = CoreDataHelper.sharedInstance.getItems()
```

Comment: Are you calling `NSKeyedUnArchiver` somewhere?

Comment: No I am not. Should I be?

Comment: No, you shouldn't. `NSKeyedUnArchiver` calls `initWithCoder` which is a part of the error message.

Comment: Is `Oil.blendswith` an `NSSet`, an `NSOrderedSet` or Transformable([Tag])?

Comment: a Transformable([Tag])

Answer (score 0):

If you debug this code does it ever step into the Tag `init` function? It appears the compiler is not seeing your Tag.init function which is most likely due to your Data Model for the Oil object not correctly setting the class type of the `blendsWith` property.

Check your data model for Oil and make sure that `blendsWith` is set to the correct type of Tag.

EDIT:
For Core Data to pick up your class setting you might need to add the `objc` flag before your class definition:

```
@objc(Tag)
public class Tag ...
```

Comment: Can you verify that your data model sets the blendsWith array in the Oil entity with the correct Tag class?

Comment: Also check my edit about adding the `objc` flag before your class declaration.

Comment: Can confirm its correct and the Objc flag doesn't fix the problem. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: When you confirmed it was hitting the breakpoint I didn't think the objc flag was going to help, but it was worth a shot. It does appear iOS is correctly seeing your class assignment.

Answer (score 0):

A `Transformable` is usually coded by CoreData to `Data` (stored just as that), and coding an `NSManagedObject` may do things you do not expect. Decoding it could make things „more“ unexpected. (Coding done by `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` automatically on assignment/use.)

If you want to use `Transformable` then making it an `NSManagedObject` is pointless due to the argument above. (I at least have no experience with it, and have not heard what use it would have.)

So its usually `Transformable` OR `CoreData-relationships`(with `NSManagedObject`s) to model one relationship in CoreData, but not both to model a single one.